# How to add custom rewrite rule to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress page called products which is using a custom template i want them to be able to click a link such as

```
/products/games/
```

which rewrites to

```
/products/?cat=games
```

is this possible, i've tried

```
RewriteRule products/(.*)/$    products/?cat=$1 [L]
```

placed in the .htaccess but this doesn't work it just takes me to the wordpress 404 page.

Comment: There's an entire API dedicated to rewrites:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
[Flush rewrite rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)